# Rails 4 + Paperclip: How do I grab the URL to a paperclip file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization, paperclip

I am using the [Active Model Serializer Gem](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) in my Rails API and I cannot seem to grab the URL to the images associated with a record.  For example, I have a `Client` that has the following columns: `before_front_file_name`, `before_front_content_type`, `before_front_file_size`, `before_front_updated_at` but as you might know, the URL to the attachment is saved at `before_front.url` which is NOT a column on the `Client` table.

Is there a way to include that when I make the call to my API to retrieve this client?  I'd like to be able to include a method that retrieves the URL and inludes it in the `Client` hash that is returned.

If there is another way to accomplish this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I found out I could include a custom method:

```
class API::ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :name, :address, :get_image

    def get_image
        object.before_front.url if object.before_front.present?
    end
end
```